# How can I click on all links of website with mechanize in ruby?

Tags: ruby, mechanize-ruby

I have a small problem. 
I want to click on some links on a certain website. 
There are 31 links on the site and each represents a calendarentry. 
I just want to find some links and by clicking on them the "status" changes and so I can keep this calendar up to date. 
This is what I've got so far.

```
require "rubygems"
require "mechanize"

agent = Mechanize.new
agent.get('http://funnysite.com/all_links.php')

available = agent.page.links_with(:href => %r{&status=0})

available.each do |link|
  agent.page.link_with(:text => link.text).click
end
```

Is there a better an clearer way to write this? This code only works "sometimes". Does anyone know a correct implementation of this?
Thanx in advance :)

Comment: What if you're intermittently getting pages with a different sort of content such as a login form or are being rate limited?

Comment: What do you mean saying sometimes?